# Error in SQL : invalid input syntax for type integer:

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use cast function for a query where the `customer_id` is given in `varchar` constraint .
I'm trying to use cast to amend it to an int so that I can use it in my query, but its not working and I don't understand it why.

I was expecting that

```
select cast (customer_id as integer) as cust_id from customer
```

would eventually give back the customer-id as integer so that I can run it in my query, but its just giving my error message.

Comment: It might be better to add some sample code with a minimum viable question you're trying to ask because its not entirely clear from your description.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well, apparently you have at least one `customer_id` that can not be converted to an integer. The full error message actually includes the value that can't be converted. https://dbfiddle.uk/6Wgyouy8

Comment: 1) Add the complete error message(as text) to the body of your question. 2) There are a many reasons this could happen. Off the top of my head: a) `select ''::integer; ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: ""` b) `select '1.2'::integer; ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "1.2"` c) `select 'a'::integer; ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "a"`

Comment: Is your customerID actually a number of some sort? Seems that either there are some alpha characters in it or you are trying to put too big of a number into too small of a type. Some sample data and your DDL would really help tremendously.

Comment: @ClearlyClueless. `select '2147483648'::integer; ERROR:  value "2147483648" is out of range for type integer`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver That's the problem. Its out of range for integer. You need to use a BIGINT instead. INTEGER has range `-2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647` and the our of range value is the maximum. BIGINT has range `-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807`

Comment: You are still not paying  attention. The Op's error is "invalid input syntax for type integer:". I was demonstrating that it was not an out of range issue as you suggested: ...too big of a number into too small of a type". The error message you get for that is different.

Comment: I mistook your comment as an update from the OP thinking they had started receiving a different error message after changing their query.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I managed to solve the issue!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried replacing `integer` with `int`

```
select cast (customer_id as int) as cust_id from customer
```

or `bigint`

```
select cast (customer_id as bigint) as cust_id from customer
```

also note that in this [tutorial](https://sql.sh/fonctions/cast) `int`, `bigint` or `integer` is not officially supported for `CAST()`

Comment: I tried to execute both queries above, but still getting the same error message back, unfortunately.

Comment: what about `CONVERT(INT, customer_id)` ?

Comment: I tried that earlier , but its states that 'in' does not exist. Not sure why its not letting me convert from varchar to int, never had this issue before, so thank you for the help

Comment: Yeah I'm searching a bit, never had this problem before too, maybe `CAST(customer_id AS NUMERIC)` or `CAST( CAST(customer_id AS NUMERIC) AS INT)` ?

Comment: not working neither, I believe something is off with  the table, because on other tables it works fine

Comment: maybe yes, sorry to not have been able to help you

Comment: 1) That is not the SQL docs, that is some random tutorial. 2) Read [Numeric types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html). 3) Your answer does not address the error "... invalid input syntax  ...".  Either supply a correct answer or delete the answer.